# Trouble accessing WooCommerce order ID within filter

Tags: woocommerce

What are some ways to get the current order ID from within a callback function hooked to a WooCommerce filter where the callback is **not passed the order ID by default**?

Example hook to a WooCommerce filter that meets this criteria:

`add_filter('woocommerce_get_downloadable_file_urls', array('fooClass', 'fooFighter'), 10, 4);`

This hook passess the following variables to the callback:

1. $file_urls
2. $product_id
3. $variation_id
4. $item

I have looked into accessing the order ID through $woocommerce by defining it as a global. In this instance (when WooCommerce sends the customer the completed order email), $woocommerce does not contain a WC_Order object.

For additional information, I am attempting to use the aforementioned hook to create custom download links for specific WooCommerce products. This filter is called each time a downloadable product is listed on the completed order email and again on the order complete page). To create the custom link, I need the order_id.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while since this was asked, but I stumbled upon the same problem today and fixed it by putting the following code inside my filter function.

```
global $woocommerce;
$orderId = $woocommerce->woocommerce_email->emails['WC_Email_New_Order']->object->id;
```

The $woocommerce-woocommerce_email->emails variable is only set when sending out e-mails, so adding some checks might also be necessary.

Hope this helps someone someday. :)

Answer (score 1):

I also know this is pretty old, but just wanted to note that for WooCommerce 2.2 the `get_downloadable_file_urls()` method is deprecated in favor of `get_item_downloads()`. That means the that appropriate filter would now be `woocommerce_get_item_downloads`.

```
return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_item_downloads', $files, $item, $this );
```

The third parameter is `$this` which since `get_item_downloads()` is a method in the `WC_Abstract_Order` abstract (responsible for WC_Order) would ultimately mean it is the `$order` object and `$order->id` would be the ID.